# Plugin for WordPress and Foundation Reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugin, wordpress

I figure that someone here probably knows a much better way to do this. I'm still figuring out AJAX and jQuery, so I consider that I still need to master quite a bit of knowledge.

My function extends Foundation 4 Reveal's functionality in a few ways:

- Uses WordPress AJAX to dynamically pull in content to populate a modal div.
- Centers the modal div and allows it to be variable width.
- Adds paging navigation from the modal window that when triggered will close the open modal window, then open the previous/next modal content.

While I feel like I've managed to figure out a lot on my own, my code isn't optimal; I would greatly appreciate any feedback or insights on ways to improve it, or things that I should avoid.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.displayPost = function() {

event.preventDefault();

var post_id = $(this).data("id");
var id = "#" + post_id;

// Check if the reveal modal for the specific post id doesn't already exist by checking for it's length
if($(id).length == 0 ) {
    // We'll add an ID to the new reveal modal; we'll use that same ID to check if it exists in the future.
    var modal = $('<div>').attr('id', post_id ).addClass('reveal-modal').appendTo('body');
    var ajaxURL = MyAjax.ajaxurl;
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {"action": "load-content", post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            modal.empty().html(response).append('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            modal.bind('opened', function() {
                // Reset visibility to hidden and set display: none on closed reveal-modal divs, for some reason not working by default when reveal close is triggered on .secondary links  
                $(".reveal-modal:not('.reveal-modal.open')").css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display' : 'none'})
                // Trigger resize 
                $(window).trigger('resize');
            return false;
            });
        }
    });
}
 //If the div with the ID already exists just open it.
 else {
     $(id).foundation('reveal', 'open');
 }

 // Recalculate left margin on window resize to allow for absolute centering of variable width elements
 $(window).resize(function(){
     var left;
        left = Math.max($(window).width() - $(id).outerWidth(), 0) / 2;
        $(id).css({
            left:left + $(window).scrollLeft()
        });
 });
}

 })(jQuery);

 // Apply the function when we click on the .reveal link
 // (document).ready won't work on any reveal-modal divs added subsequently
 // after page load via AJAX so use .on instead.
 jQuery(document).on("click", ".reveal,.secondary", function() {
  jQuery(this).displayPost();

 });

  // Close open modal via secondary paging links; target parent div id.
  jQuery(document).on("click", ".secondary", function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id");
  jQuery(id).foundation('reveal', 'close');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

- **L15**, **L26**, **L31-60**: Inconsistent indentation levels.
- **L4-43**: Consider indenting this block.
- **L04**: I don't see the point in storing the ID rather than the jQuery object itself. Instead of `var id = "#" + post_id;`, go ahead and store the object: `var $id = $("#" + post_id);`. Modify the references as appropriate on **L11** and **L33**.
- **L13**: Your code for appending the modal is nice in terms of the builder pattern, but it might be better just as:

  ```
  var modal = $("<div class='reveal-modal' id='" + post_id + "'></div>").appendTo("body")
  ```
- **L14**: There's no point in declaring the `ajaxURL` variable. Instead, just go ahead and use `{ ... url: MyAjax.ajaxurl, ... }` on **L17**,
- **L20**: The jQuery API documentation on `.html()` [notes a specific case](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) in which it's important to use `.empty().html()`. I don't believe this applies in your case; you don't need the call to `.empty()` since `.html()` will effectively empty the container first.
- **L21**: Since jQuery 1.7, [`.on()` is preferred](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).
- **L58-59**: This part is at best senseless and wrong, and at worst unintuitive and potentially deceptive. By extracting the ID attribute and using it as a selector, you're effectively matching against the ID without the `#`. This either means that it doesn't do what you think it does, in which case you should use:

  ```
  jQuery(this).closest("div").foundation("reveal", "close");
  ```

  or you for some reason have a construct like `<div id='span'>` and you really mean to match all `span` elements instead of `#span`. In that case, I strongly suggest you restructure your HTML to be more semantically sensible, and to leave a comment explicitly detailing that that's your intention.